# Can't deplopy UWP to local machine. "The required framework CoreRuntime.1.0.appx failed to install"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uwp

The full error message is

> DEP0800 : The required framework "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows
>   Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime\1.0.\AppX\x86\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0.appx"
>   failed to install. Deployment Add operation with target volume C: on
>   Package Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0_1.0.23819.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
>   from:(Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0.appx)  failed with error
>   0x80073CFC. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help
>   diagnosing app deployment issues.

In Configuration Manager, I have checked the build and deploy checkboxes.

I cannot deploy to local machine or simulator.

Repairing Visual Studio did not work.

I am on Windows Insider Preview Build 14946, using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

Comment: So is this a new issue after upgrading to 14946?

Comment: I didn't notice it until 14946, I am not entirely sure when it started to occur.

Comment: I hadn't done any UWP development for a couple of releases, but the problem exists on newly created and existing projects.

Comment: Problem still exists in 14951

Answer (score 3):

Run in the PowerShell with Administrator:

```
Add-AppxPackage "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime\1.0\.\AppX\x86\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0.appx"
```

Resolved for me.